# Ubuntu Installed - Stuck in Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Okay, so allow me to be the first to point out that I know little to nothing about Ubuntu. I own a HP Pavilion with Windows 10. My dad made me a Boot CD of Ubuntu 15.10 which installed dual-boot without a problem. I used it happily for about two weeks before I broke it.

I was trying to watch Amazon Instant Video on my laptop last night. For the life of me, I couldn't get the thing to load on Ubuntu, so I switched the laptop off, restarted it and spammed the esc key, as well as a few others, until Windows loaded again.

I should probably also point out: Since installing Ubuntu, my laptop has always automatically booted up to it. I've never encountered a start-up screen (GRUB?) asking me which OS I'd like to boot. I didn't even realize that this wasn't strictly normal until today.

So I watched my Amazon Videos, went to sleep, woke up, and I wanted to go back to Ubuntu. This is where I'm stuck, because I don't have a GRUB, and the only things I have in my Boot Device Manager are two 'OS Boot Managers' and one 'Boot from EFI File' which, frankly, seems to just be a lot of empty folders. Not a clue what it is. Both 'OS Boot Managers' lead to Windows 10. Esc leads to Windows 10. I cannot escape Windows 10.

Disk back in the laptop, I get the option to Boot from CD/DVD. This brings me to the screen I saw when I first installed Ubuntu. It has the options to Install Ubuntu, or Try without Installing. I try installing again, but it's already installed, so no dice there.

Also, at some point, my laptop flipped out and had to fix disk problems. I think I'm stressing it out. It's stressing me out, too. I just want to get back to Ubuntu. Help? Please?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, 8.1, or 10 you have to change the power button options to shut down windows then uncheck fast boot to keep windows from hibernating